# read response from redirection url using webView in flutter

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, webview, payment-gateway

I was trying to add a payment gateway using WebView flutter library.On successful completion of payment, the gateway redirects to a return url or webhook with transaction response. Now instead of redirection to some outside url, I want redirection to my app and want to read the status of transaction from response that is sent.
All I want to know whether transaction is success or fail.

'''

```
WebView(
  navigationDelegate: (action) {
    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
  },
  onPageStarted: (url) => _onPageStart(url),
  onPageFinished: (url) => _onPageFinish(url),
   gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
  debuggingEnabled: true,
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  initialUrl: url,
  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webcontroller) {
    _controller = webcontroller;
  },
),

void _onPageStart(url) {
  Future<String> future = _controller
      .runJavascriptReturningResult("window.document.body.outerHTML");
  future.then((data) {
    print("ONpage start $data");
  });
}


Future<void> _onPageFinish(url) async {
    Future<String> future = _controller
        .runJavascriptReturningResult("window.document.body.outerHTML");
    future.then((data) {
      print(data);
    });
  }
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is simply **add a javascript channel** to your webview like this:

```
   WebView(
      onPageStarted: (url) => _onPageStart(url),
      onPageFinished: (url) => _onPageFinish(URL),
      gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
      debuggingEnabled: true,
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      initialUrl: URL,
      javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
                _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
              },
    );
    
/*
create functionality on your web side also for this javascript channel
use the name 'Toaster' on the web side also ( use same name on web side and app side , name can be anything 'toaster' is example shown here)
 */
    JavascriptChannel _toasterJavascriptChannel(BuildContext context) {
        return JavascriptChannel(
            name: 'Toaster',
            onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
              );
            });
      }
```

When you click on any function on the website, call this Toaster javascriptChannel on the web side and it will listen on the app side also

Comment: Thanks for reply but I don't have control over website as the webpage is of payment gateway only and can just pass the redirection url.

Comment: I have a suggestion for you. This is the way i implemented the web payment gateway. 1. Call an API which returns a url to the payment gateway. 2. Server side guys should wrap the payment gateway inside our web page and handle the responses and requests from there itself. And on final result page we can add a button which can return our desired action